# How can I use nuitka with virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, nuitka

I am using nuitka for my project. It has some 3rd party modules as dependencies and I am using virtualenv.

How can I use nuitka with virtualenv?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While compilation worked perfect, I had import error at execution time on all packages that were installed in virtualenv folder, even is virtualenv was activated by `workon`.

Extending `PYTHONPATH` before running the resulted `.exe` has solved the issue though:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/pystack/.virtualenvs/occam_1.0_pandas_0.16.2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

Probably using the `--recurse-directory=MODULE/PACKAGE` would also do it.

Comment: im having the same issue and while that might work, i want my exe to run independently of the environment, so i dont want to modify system env variable to make it run and would prefer not to install py modules at system level. also, the --recurse-directory argument doesnt get recognized by my nuitka despite being the last version. any idea?